# Node JS memory leak on linux

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, jimp

Hello I have a memory leak in node js that happens only in production mode on my vps which runs on a Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. In dev mode on Windows 10 this memory leaks does not occure.
The code with problem on linux is the following:

```
  async compressImage(
    imageLocation: string,
    outputWidth: number,
    quality = 60,
  ):Promise<Buffer> {
    try {
      const file: any = await Jimp.read(imageLocation);
      const buffer: Buffer = await file
        .resize(outputWidth, Jimp.AUTO)
        .quality(quality)
        .getBufferAsync(Jimp.MIME_JPEG);

      return buffer;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  }
```

This function runs in a for loop for 3 times.

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory leak?

Comment: When this function is called on an image of 3MB the RAM goes to 500MB and then it stays there. It nevers goes back to 80,90MB